# Add and Remove textbox in table using Javascript error

Tags: javascript, html-table

I want to add and remove `textbox` in table.

I did add `textbox` in `table`.

Am confused to remove `textbox` in table.

This is my code:

```js
$(function () {
   $('.more').on('click', function () {
        var $table = $('#input_fields');
        var $tr = $table.find('tr').eq(0).clone();
        $tr.appendTo($table).find('input').val('');
    });
});

$(function () {
   $('.delete').on('click', function () {
   
    });
});
```

```css
.delete{color:#ff0000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="quick_post" method="post"> 
    <table id="input_fields">
        <tr> 
            <td><input class="orderinput" type="text" name="product[]" /></td> 
            <td><input class="orderquan" type="text" name="quantity[]" size="1" maxlength="3" /></td>
            <td> <span class='delete'>Delete</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<input class="more" type="button" value="Addmore" name="addmore" />
```

This is my sample code link: https://jsfiddle.net/vo9j2LcL/

Please help me to `remove` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to listen the click event on a dynamically generated element.

```js
$(function() {
  // cache the table reference
  var $table = $('#input_fields');

  // keep a cloned copy to generate new
  var $tr = $table.find('tr').eq(0).clone();

  $('.more').on('click', function() {
    // clone to generate new and then append
    $tr.clone().appendTo($table).find('input').val('');
  });

  // set click event handler
  $table.on('click', '.delete', function() {
    // check number of tr
    if ($('#input_fields').find('tr').length > 1) {
      // remove the tr corresponds to clicked element
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.delete {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="quick_post" method="post">
  <table id="input_fields">
    <tr>
      <td><input class="orderinput" type="text" name="product[]" /></td>
      <td><input class="orderquan" type="text" name="quantity[]" size="1" maxlength="3" /></td>
      <td> <span class='delete'>Delete</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<input class="more" type="button" value="Addmore" name="addmore" />
```

Comment: Can you please tell me  Cannot delete all the rows

Comment: I mean user cannot delete all the rows

Comment: @RameshS `$table.find('tr').remove()`

Comment: @RameshS : ok, before deleting check length of rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154673/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-pranav-c-balan).